# Objects.equals for jUnit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

First, I am new to Java, so hopefully this isn't something terribly simple, but I am trying to do some unit-testing and I am not getting the old green light in Eclipse. To my problem:

So, I have two Objects, both of class Fraction and I am simply trying to make sure that my method (multiplyThem) is.... uh... functioning correctly.

Code (edited to show what I have now):

```
private Fraction newFraction, otherFraction, thirdFraction;

@Before
public void setUp(){
    newFraction = new Fraction(2, 3);
    otherFraction = new Fraction(1, 5);
    thirdFraction = new Fraction(2, 15);
}

@Test
public void testMultiplyEm() {
    System.out.println(newFraction.multiplyEm(otherFraction));
    System.out.println(thirdFraction);
    assertEquals("Fractions don't equal", newFraction.multiplyEm(otherFraction), thirdFraction);
}
```

In the method `multiplyEm`, the return type is a Fraction and it multiplies two numerators and two denominators before calling on another function called simplify. Then it returns the simplified Fraction.

I used `System.out.println` on the two individually and got the exact same thing printed to screen. I know that doesn't always mean they ARE the same, but perhaps `Objects.equals` isn't what I should be using here. The objects are simply two ints: `Fraction x = new Fraction(int y, int z)`.

I am not sure why this fails the test. Anyone have any ideas? Would be grateful for a way to correctly write a unit test for it!

Fraction Class method multiplyEm:

```
public Fraction multiplyEm(Fraction otherFraction){
        int newNumerator = this.numerator * otherFraction.numerator;
        int newDenominator = this.denominator * otherFraction.denominator;
        Fraction newFraction = new Fraction(newNumerator, newDenominator);
        return newFraction;
    }
```

Comment: What is printed is irrelevant. Objects.equals() uses fraction.equals(fraction2). So if you haven't overridden equals(Object), then a fraction is only equal to itself.

Comment: Have you implemented the equals and hashCode methods for the Fraction class? The Assert.assertEquals and Objects.assertEquals both delegate to Fraction.equals to check the equality

Comment: I think you are asking if I used Fraction.equals anywhere in my Fraction Class (or .hashCode)? If that is what you are asking, no I haven't. I guess I should post my code from the class, too. Perhaps that is where I am really screwing something up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running into the difference between object identity and equality. The equals method checks either the identity or the equality based on the implementation. The `==` operator always checks the identity of an object.

The [Objects.equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)) method checks for null references and then delegates the check to the equals method of the first argument.

The equals method inherited from the Object class checks the identity of the objects. That the object reference is the same. The `Fraction` class should override the equals implementation. There are some [rules](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=17) for correctly implementing the equals method. There is a contract for the equals and hashCode methods that needs to be honoured for the Java Collections to work correctly.

Included in the JUnit framework is an [assertEquals](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)) method. That is the method usually used to test equality in a unit test.

Comment: Ahhh, I finally realized what you were suggesting. I need to override the equals() method myself! I did it and it worked. Thank you! Also, I really like [this page](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-equals-method-in-java/) for simple explination.